# Asynchronous socket.io for lots of concurrent messages

Tags: concurrency, async, websockets, ember.js

We have a web application which currently operates like this on a typical view/page:

- the front has to display 100+ "previews" (in the form of `base64` images)
- each of this preview is built on-demand by the backend when the front requests it
- a pool of 8 standard `ajax` requests are running in queue until all previews are loaded

Let me illustrate this with a picture:

[image: Initial loading]

Sometimes the user does something that modifies some of the previews and those (and only those) have to be requested again by the front. In this case it goes like this:

[image: Modified previews loading]

At this moment, waiting for 100+ previews to load initially can take a long time (between 30 and 50 seconds), which is very annoying.

**Before coming to the actual question, let me state a few points:**

- each preview is totally independent from the others
- each preview can be built almost instantly by the back-end
- each preview's `base64` payload weighs virtually nothing (a few `kb`)
- establishing an `http` connection actually takes most of the time
- of course, no more than around 8 `ajax` requests can work concurrently
- if the user leaves to another view while 8 requests are being handled, the browser will wait to have some room in his `ajax` queue before loading elements from the new view, which is very annoying (the new view can remain empty for many seconds before something happens)
- we can't *bulk* all the previews in one big request because sometimes (and it's not predictable), it happens that a particular preview takes a lot of time (several seconds) to built, and we don't want to penalize the other previews which could be loaded much faster

**So, my questions are:**

- could using a `socket` dramatically improve connection time so that the app is much more responsive at initial loading and in case of modifications in previews?
- could messages exchanged in this `socket` be asynchronous so that if we ask for 100+ previews at the same time, they will all be loaded very quickly? And if so, is there a maximum number of concurrent messages in the socket?
- can *all* the concurrent messages for which the front is currently waiting for, be instantly dropped if the user exits this view to visit another one? or does it even matter if there are virtually no concurrent messages limit?

We're using `EmberJS` for the front with `EmberData` and `Flask` for the back.

Answer (score 3):

> Could using a socket dramatically improve connection time so that the app is much more responsive at initial loading and in case of modifications in previews?

Yes.  Sockets are designed specifically for this.

> Could messages exchanged in this socket be asynchronous so that if we ask for 100+ previews at the same time, they will all be loaded very quickly?

The design would most likely take the form: receive a message, update a tile.  It would be asynchronous in the sense that it would not require either a partial or complete page reload.

> Is there a maximum number of concurrent messages in the socket?

One, as far as I know.  But you can receive serial messages very rapidly.

> can all the concurrent messages for which the front is currently waiting for, be instantly dropped if the user exits this view to visit another one?

Send a message to the host to the effect that the view has changed.  Program the host to respond accordingly.

**See Also**
http://socket.io/
http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there really no standard way to exchange messages in parallel, as all the previews are thoroughly independent from one another?

Comment: Set up multiple websocket channels.  But really you should only need one.  You could also send updates for all 100 previews in the same packet, but you told me that they're all independent.  You'll have to experiment to see what kind of arrangement works the best for your particular application.